# Traefik as a proxy for Docker container with host machines network

Tags: docker, docker-compose, traefik

I would like to set up the following scenario:

- One physical machine with Docker containers
- traefik in a container with network `backend`
- another container which is using the host machines network (`network_mode: host`)

Traefik successfully finds the container and adds it with the IP address `127.0.0.1` which obviously not accessible from the traefik container (different network/bridge).

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
    traefik:
        image: traefik
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
        volumes:
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
            - ./traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml
        networks:
            - backend
     app:
         image: my_app
         labels:
             - "traefik.enable=true"
             - "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:myapp.example"
             - "traefik.port=8080"
         network_mode: host
networks:
    backend:
        driver: bridge
```

The `app` container is added with

```
Server      URL                     Weight 
server-app  http://127.0.0.1:8080   0
Load Balancer: wrr
```

Of course I can access `app` with `http://127.0.0.1:8080` on the host machine or with `http://$HOST_IP:8080` from the traefik container.

Can I somehow convince traefik to use another IP for the container?

Thanks!

Comment: Try adding the app to the backend network.

Comment: Forgot to add `network_mode` to the app container's config.

Comment: i am using dockertoolbox for windows, docker-machine ip is 192.168.99.100, but when i run my app in network_mode: host  , it is taking 127.0.0.1 instead of 192.168.99.100. can u help with this?

Comment: Seems like they're working on this in the newer versions https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/5559 Workaround: https://github.com/containous/traefik/issues/5535#issuecomment-537048178

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a common docker network, traefik won't be able to route to your container. Since you're using host networking, you could access it directly. Or if you need to only access it through the proxy, then place it on the backend network. If you need some ports published on the host and others proxied through traefik, then place it on the backend network and publish the ports you need to publish, rather than using the host network directly.

With [recent versions of traefik](https://github.com/traefik/traefik/pull/5698/files) and [docker](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/40007), it is possible to have the proxy connect back to the docker host for ports. You need to define the `host.docker.internal` hostname on Linux using (this should be provided automatically on Docker Desktop environments):

```yaml
    traefik:
        image: traefik
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
        volumes:
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
            - ./traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml
        networks:
            - backend
        extra_hosts:
            - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
```

Comment: You are right, I've added my backed statically, as it always runs.

Comment: i am using dockertoolbox for windows, docker-machine ip is 192.168.99.100, but when i run my app in network_mode: host  , it is taking 127.0.0.1 instead of 192.168.99.100. can u help with this?

Comment: Discussing about the "need" is off topic. the HOW is the thing that matters. For example, I *need* to setup a web service receiving request from load balancer and send multicast/broadcast through host network. Using a backend network is not a solution to everything

Comment: Some docker services need `network_mode: host` in order to work